# Qt4 QTableWidget make Colums resized to contents, interactive and aligned to tableborder

Tags: c++, qt4, qtablewidget

This code

```
horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

stretches the cloumns of a `qtablewidget`. I want them to be stretched, what means be aligned to the border of the `qtablewidget`, no matter how big it is.

I also want them not to be smaller than their contents and to be resizable by the user.

This means, I would have to use

```
horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Interactive);
horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

at once, which is not possible.

I know I can give every column another view, like

```
horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Interactive);
horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

but this ist not what I want. I want the colums to be

- not smaller than their contents
- resizable by the user
- aligned to the border of the qtablewidget

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should reimplement sizeHintForColumn. The below code will give you a start.

```
int TableWidget::sizeHintForColumn(int column) const  // to get resize on all rows in the column, i.e. not only visible rows.
{
   if(d_resizeColumnsOnVisibleRowsOnly)
      return QTableView::sizeHintForColumn(column);
   if(!model())
      return -1;
   QStyleOptionViewItem option(viewOptions());
   int hint(0);
   QModelIndex index;
   QWidget* w(0);
   for(int row(0);row<rowCount();++row)
   {
       index=model()->index(row,column);
       w=cellWidget(row,column);
       int hint_for_row(qMax(itemDelegate(index)->sizeHint(option,index).width(),(w?w->sizeHint().width():0)));
       hint=qMax(hint,hint_for_row);
   }
   return showGrid()?hint+1:hint;
}
```